# Matlab function surf axes going from high to low I want low to high?

Tags: matlab

Last question on this I swear.

Right now the plot of surf has the dates going from newest (i.e today) at the left hand side to oldest on the right hand side. I would like it to be the other wat round but keep everything else the same.

Is there a quick way to do this? Without having to reorganise the input data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply revert the direction of the axis. If it's the x-axis, you write

```
set(gca,'XDir','reverse')
```

`gca` grabs the handle to the currently active axes, so make sure that the surface is on the active figure, or store the axis handle somewhere and pass it instead as first argument to `set`.

Just replace the `X` in `XDir` if you want to do it for a different axis.

Comment: +1 simple but useful. I was wondering about that a number of times, and never cared to look..

Comment: @angainor: It's actually quite nice what you can do fiddling with properties (like playing with the mouse etc in figure props). Yet I'd always like to have access to even more properties.

Answer (score 0):

This can be set using axis properties:

Direction of increasing values. A mode controlling the direction of increasing axis values. Axes form a right-hand coordinate system. By default:

x-axis values increase from left to right. To reverse the direction of increasing x values, set this property to reverse.

`set(gca,'XDir','reverse')`

y-axis values increase from bottom to top (2-D view) or front to back (3-D view). To reverse the direction of increasing y values, set this property to reverse.

`set(gca,'YDir','reverse')`

z-axis values increase pointing out of the screen (2-D view) or from bottom to top (3-D view). To reverse the direction of increasing z values, set this property to reverse.

```
set(gca,'ZDir','reverse')
```